# Decomposes a unit vector into the kronecker product of three unit vectors

Tags: statistics, optimization, computational-mathematics, kronecker-product

I want to get the optimal solution to the following equation

$$\mathop{\rm{min}}_ {\| \boldsymbol{v}_i \| = 1
    \atop
    i= 1,2,3}  \| \boldsymbol{w} - \boldsymbol{v}_3 \otimes \boldsymbol{v}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{v}_1 \|^2$$

where $\boldsymbol{v}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{ p_i\times 1}$,  $\boldsymbol{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{ p_1 p_2 p_3\times 1}$  is given and $\| \boldsymbol{w}\| = 1$.

I want to get the best estimate of $\boldsymbol{v}_i.$

I can get $p_{i+1}p_{i+2}$ $v_1^i/v_j^i$'s , $j = 2,\ldots,p_i$, where $v_j^i$ denotes the $j$-th entries of $\boldsymbol{v}_i$ and $i+1$, $i+2$ are computed modulo 3. Let $$\hat{\dfrac{v_1^i}{v_j^i}} = \dfrac{1}{p_{i+1}p_{i+2}} \sum v_1^i/v_j^i , j = 2,\ldots,p_i$$, then we can get the estimator $\hat{\boldsymbol{v}_i}$ under $\|\boldsymbol{v}_i\|=1.$

But I dont know whether this solution is optimal or appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\div#1{\op{div}\LR{#1}}
\def\mod#1{\op{mod}\LR{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\t{\otimes}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\x{\hat x}  \def\y{\hat y}  \def\z{\hat z}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracBR#1#2{\BR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sijk{\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\:}
\def\w{w_{ijk}}
$Define the standard basis vectors using an index which
acts as a mnemonic for their dimensionality, i.e.
$$
e_j\in\bbR{J},\quad
e_k\in\bbR{K},\quad etc
$$
A basis vector from a higher dimensional space can be written as a triple Kronecker product $(\t)$ of lower dimensional basis vectors, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&e_m = e_i\t e_j\t e_k \qiq M = IJK \\
&m = k + (j-1)K + (i-1)JK \\
&\qquad\; i = 1 \:+ \;\:\div{m-1,\,JK} \\
&\qquad\; j = 1 \:+ \;\:\div{\mod{m-1,\,JK},\,K} \\
&\qquad\; k = 1 \:+ \mod{\mod{m-1,\,JK},\,K} \\
}$$
Thus an arbitrary vector $a\in\bbR{M}$ can be expanded in two different ways
$$\eqalign{
a &= \sum_{m=1}^{M}\: a_m\,e_m 
&= \Sijk a_{ijk}\;\:{e_i\t e_j\t e_k}\\
}$$
using the index mappings shown above.

The scalar coefficients are numerically identical
$\:\LR{a_m = a_{ijk}}$.

The Frobenius product $(:)$ is extremely useful in *Matrix Calculus*
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
and it interacts nicely with the Kronecker product
$$\eqalign{
\l
 &= \LR{A\otimes B\otimes C}:\LR{X\otimes Y\otimes Z} \\
 &= \LR{A:X}\otimes\LR{B:Y}\otimes\LR{C:Z} \\
 &= \LR{A:X}\,\LR{B:Y}\,\LR{C:Z} \\
}$$
The derivative of a unit vector is well known
$$\eqalign{
 \x &= \frac{x}{\|x\|} \qiq
d\x &= \fracLR{I-\x\x^T}{\|x\|}dx \\
}$$

---

Write the objective function using the above notation
$$\eqalign{
 \l &= \tfrac12\LR{\x\t\y\t\z-w} : \LR{\x\t\y\t\z-w} \\
}$$
Assume that $(\y,\z)$ are fixed and try to find the optimal $\x$.

Calculate the gradient wrt the unconstrained $x$ vector
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= \LR{\x\t\y\t\z-w} : \LR{d\x\t\y\t\z} \\
 &= \LR{\y:\y}\LR{\z:\z}\,\LR{\x:d\x}
\;-\; \Sijk\w\:\LR{e_j:\y}\LR{e_k:\z}\,\LR{e_i:d\x} \\
 &= \LR{\x\;-\;\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k\,e_i}:d\x \\
 &= \fracLR{I-\x\x^T}{\|x\|}\LR{\x\;-\;\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k\,e_i}:dx \\
 &= \fracLR{\x\x^T-I}{\|x\|}\LR{\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k\,e_i}:dx \\
 &= {\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k}\fracLR{\x_i\x-e_i}{\|x\|} : dx \\
\grad{\l}{x}
 &= {\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k}\fracLR{\x_i\x-e_i}{\|x\|} \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and calculate the least square solution for $\x$
$$\eqalign{
&\LR{{\Sijk\w\:\x_i\y_j\z_k}}\x = {\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k}\:e_i \\
&\x = \frac{{\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k}\:e_i}{{\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k\:\x_i}} \\
}$$
However, since $\x$ is a unit vector, it's easier to calculate
the numerator and normalize it
$$\eqalign{
x = {\Sijk\w\:\y_j\z_k}\:e_i \;\;\qiq \x = \frac{x}{\|x\|} \\
}$$
The least squares solutions for $(\y,\z)$ are completely analogous
$$\eqalign{
&y = {\Sijk\w\:\x_i\z_k}\:e_j \qiq \y = \frac{y}{\|y\|} \\
&z = {\Sijk\w\:\x_i\y_j}\:e_k \qiq \z = \frac{z}{\|z\|} \\
}$$
Alternating Least Squares (ALS) iterations quickly converge to the optimal triplet $\LR{\x,\y,\z}$